# Failed To Install syslinux on USBDRIVE with Mac OS X

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, syslinux

I am creating Ubuntu Server 13.10 Bootable USBDRIVE with command line using Mac OS X, In this i tried to install Syslinux on USBDRIVE by using syslinux command by following:

```
xxx-Mac:~xxx$ sudo syslinux /dev/disk2s1
```

here i am using disk2s1 for my usbdrive but i got following error:

```
-bash: syslinux: command not found
```

What is alternative to install syslinux on usbdrive, Mac OS X dont include any syslinux command?

Comment: Why are you going to run a production Linux server on a thumb drive? That seems silly.

Comment: I am not run production server on USBDRIVE, I am creating bootable usbdrive so that i can install linux server on another PC using that usbdrive.

Comment: OS X does not come bundled with syslinux... you could try to compile the package downloading all the requirements but it is to much effort. you should try using unebotwin or similar tools. unebootwin sometimes works other not